# How to create list based on another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have string list with words and I need to create another list based on the length of each element of the first list. If element in first list has even length, then in the second list will be true.

Example: List is

```
"Hello", "big", "awesome", "world!".
```

So the second list will be:

```
false, false, false, true.
```

My logic is: "Hello".Length is 5 => false; "world!".Length is 6 => true.

Can somebody tell me please how to do it?

I need to use LINQ only.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It looks like as homework. What is the rule for `big` and `awesome`?

Comment: At least provide some starting code, like the constructor of the list of strings and the beginning of a function. We're happy to help get you past a specific problem you might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Select` lambda statement to return a new IEnumerable of whatever you want.
In this case, I used the mod operator % to check for even or odd.

```
    List<string> stringList = new List<string> { "Hello", "big", "awesome", "world!" };
    List<bool> boolList = stringList.Select(s => s.Length % 2 == 0).ToList();
    // boolList contains:  false, false, false, true
```